What is SMD IC marked " 4986V 6J701 BAA" QFN20?

" 4986V 6J701 BAA" QFN20,i do not know it is,it maybe RENESES！

Could you provide details of what device then chip is used in

It's probably a custom GreenPAK IC made by Renesas (formerly Dialog formerly Silego). The marking style is consistent with other Greenpak devices in a STQFN-20 package. Here an example of the SLG46826V from LCSC:

The package here is a bit different than in OPs picture, but I've a SLG46620 laying on my desk that uses the same package (3 pins on the short sides and 7 on the long sides) and has the same marking style.
Since Renesas offers custom preprogrammed versions of these ICs and there is no SLG4986V available off-the-shelf, it's very likely that this a custom IC.

May be irregular
